# May I send notification from Android to iOS or vice versa?

Tags: android, ios, notifications, push-notification

I need to develop an application which sends notification to other device based on current action.

The device on which I need to send notification that might be iOS device or Android device too I am not sure which device he/she is using.

I know about remote notification and push notification in Android and iOS respectively which work for either for Android or iOS only.

But I dont know about the notifications which can work between these two different OS, so If anybody can help me, it would be a great help.

Comment: Hi Jayesh, using JavaPNS library for iOS remote notification and GCM for android may solve your queries. since both are based on java only so you only need to design some architecture in java which can distinguish between iOS and android to send notification.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is sounds different and tricky,
There are two alternative to achieve this task.

- First thing you can use `Web-Service` and sending and receiving
  request & response as per that platform code. like request parmas should be fix and base on that you have to read that response.So,it could be easy task.
- Next way is long and complex.Like create background Bluetooth connection sending your     message to other device either it could be message or file.If you are sending a file then you have to read via file stream.

  But second trick have limitation and that is area both device should be in Bluetooth range.

So, i would like to prefer first way to achieve your task.

Comment: Yes, you're right that I can use web service but for that I need to send constantly request to server and then need to send notification  to other device and which could affect my application to be slower or might be battery power can be also one issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a web service that will use GCM (for Android) and  Push Notifications for (iOS). This is the *standard* way the notifications are created, but you can do other interesting stuffs with it, something like, you register your device by sending the notification tokne, OS, and a name or other details that your app stores or display and in response you get similar users/data which you can notify. When you want to notify a device/user/etc, you just send a request to the server with the name/user (something unique) and the server will get the token from the database, the OS, and will decide what to use GCM or push notificatiom, and the device will be notified.

Also there are a lots of tutorials for implementing GCM notifications and push notification, both on server side and mobile side

Answer (score 0):

"Next way is long and complex.Like create background Bluetooth connection sending your message to other device either it could be message or file.If you are sending a file then you have to read via file stream."

But still do you think it's possible to achieve ?

In some case it can be usefull, let me explain. For people (like me) who have a 5" smartphones or more (ascend mate 6.3"), they could be tempt to let their huge phone in their bag, unless you have giant pockets. So let say you also have an ipod touch in your pocket and the huge smartphone in your bag, your ipod touch can be able to inform you if you have received any mails, text, phone calls or any notification you can imagine.

Well I hope understand what I'm thinking of.